# Keep getting unidentified method 'field' for undefined method `bio' for #<User:>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I just deployed my app to Heroku and I'm facing this problem. In the sign up page:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bio %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :bio %>
  </div>
```

and in the logs

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `bio' for #<User:0x007f5e772493c0>):
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :bio %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :bio %>
      </div>
```

Any thoughts on this? Thanks
Ps. used to work fine before deployment

**EDIT**

I tried to migrate but I got this error

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3"}
Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't run the migrations thats why its unable to find the column `:bio` for user.

Run this command on your console

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Now I'm getting Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Comment: Try moving `"sqlite3"` in development and `"pg"` in production