# Getting an sqlite error when migrating after heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku, database-migration, rails-postgresql

So I deployed my app to Heroku and installed gem 'pg' and removed sqlite.
Now getting this error when I migrate locally or on Heroku

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `"sqlite3"` in development and `"pg"` in `production`

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: Now I got this error SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: parent_id: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "parent_id" integer, I tried drop:all then create then migrate but sme error

Comment: try `heroku run rake db:setup`

Comment: Just :reset my database and the migration is working fine but still getting the error but now only in the view. Which is.. ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `bio' for #<User:0x007fe52478d2d0>):

Comment: I think I have already posted answer for this error http://stackoverflow.com/a/39500764/4758119